# Test enclosing component inside a React functional component using Jest/Enzyme

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, jestjs

I have a component called `Post`, in which there is an enclosing component called `Div`. When ran test coverage, it looks like the `Div` part is **not** covered. Whereas, the `Post` got covered. How can I get the `Div` part covered. Could anyone please help?

```
const Post = ({id, title}) => (
 <Div>
  <Title name={title} />
 </Div>
);
```

Here's my test case

```
describe('Post component', () => {
  const props = {
    id: '1',
    title: 'Test',
  };
  it('renders post', () => {
    const component = shallow(<Post {...props} />);
    expect(component).toMatchSnapshot();
  });
});
```

Comment: What *are* `Div` and `Title`? Do you need to shallow render?

Comment: Those are `styled` components, just added padding and margin.

Answer (score 0):

From your comment, it looks like you have the styled components named `Div` and `Title`. If you have export statements for its functions, you can just call them here by sending their props like how you are doing shallow test for components.
If you have something like

```
export const Div = () => {}

export const Title = () => {}

export const Post = () => {}
```

Your test cases should be

```
describe('Post component', () => {
  const props = {
    id: '1',
    title: 'Test',
  };
  it('renders post', () => {
    const component = shallow(<Post {...props} />);
    expect(component).toMatchSnapshot();
  });

 it('renders Div', () => {
    const component = shallow(<Div {...props} />);
    expect(component).toMatchSnapshot();
  });

 it('renders Title', () => {
    const component = shallow(<Title {...props} />);
    expect(component).toMatchSnapshot();
  });
});
```

This way, you will have entire functional components covered.